# If the Domain of a function of real variables $\mathbb{R}$ is a line, why is the graph of a function represented in a plane?

Tags: graphing-functions, real-numbers

If the Domain of a function of real variables $\mathbb R$ is a line, why is the graph of a function of real variables representable in an $\mathbb R^2$ plane?

Is it due to the fact that the function has two sets, one of departure (the domain, the abscissae) and one of arrival (the codomain/range the ordinates) and these two "axes" are a Cartesian product $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ effectively making the function representable on a Cartesian plane?

Comment: In one word, yes. That is exactly what the graph of a function is.

Comment: Right. One dimension for the inputs, one dimension for the outputs.

Comment: Because you are drawing a picture of *pairs* of input *and* output values to see the correspondence.  You you were drawing *just* the output you'd just have a flat real line ("the output of $y = \frac 35x + 27$ is.... all the real numbers") but that wouldn't tell you any information of what numbers map to which ("so as we can see then number $64.9$ is mapped to... and that's it.... $64.9$ is mapped to by... something and by graphing only the output we have no idea what")